# Can we block creation of ephemeral pod using kubectl debug

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

For troubleshoot of a crashed container, we can create ephemeral container either

1. Inside the pod with crashed container OR
2. Creating copy of pod with crashed container
   (Ref. https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/debug/debug-application/debug-running-pod/)

I have a use case where I need to enable addition of ephemeral container in an existing pod (#1), however to prevent the creation of ephemeral container using copy of the existing pod (#2).

Is it achievable in some way?

I can see below policy configuration to block creation of ephemeral container using 'kubectl debug', however it'll block creation in both ways described above.

https://kyverno.io/policies/other/b-d/block-ephemeral-containers/block-ephemeral-containers/